# Htaccess ignore folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'im trying to make a admin system for a site, but the htaccess ruins it D:

The admin part is in a folder named `admin`.

My htacces to far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(admin)$ admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^([\wæøå]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\wæøå]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(nyhed)/([\w\d\-æøå]+)$ index.php?page=$1&nyhed=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(nyhed)/([\w\d\-æøå]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&nyhed=$2 [QSA]
```

But won't let me in that folder?

So I did a `if` in my index:

```
if($_GET["page"] == "admin"){
    header("location:http://google.com");
}
```

But that won't do anything either, and no errors D:

Comment: is the folder named "if" or "admin"

Comment: @PugganSe Oops sorry. It's named admin

Comment: its stops on the test "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d", as "admin" is a "d"irectory, the rule is aborted

Comment: @PugganSe The problem is, that it doesn't... I know it was supposed to, but `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` never really worked for me, just using it, so if one day I would be lucky, and it actually worked :D

Comment: so if you remove that row, it still dosn't work? try add: "RewriteRule ^(admintest)$ admin/index.php" and go to http: //domain/admintest

Comment: @PugganSe Uhm, that does actually work!? :O Why?

Comment: Because what he already explained: the `admin` directory that's requested in your URL exists, so it won't be rewritten.

Comment: Rewrites write from non-existent directories / files if you add the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and -f part, that is what is basically says, `if directory does not exist`

Comment: Be sure that you clean your browser's cache and/or exit and then reenter _private browsing mode_ before testing rewrite conditions. (A while ago, I had erros with configuration my rewrites only because my browser cached the first, wrong configuration and even though I used a new, now good one later, it still rewrote the request to the wrong page.)

Comment: @CodeCaster But still won't go to the admin folder, which is why I'm confused D:

Comment: So you have removed the -d and -f lines? Are you accessing the url via admin/ cos the / will not match the rule you have up there

Comment: @Sammaye No haven't removed `-d` or `-f`, and tried to both access the folder with and with out slash. And isn't only the `admin`folder, doesn't work for any other folder either... D:

Comment: Try removing those two lines and add a [PT] flag to the end of `RewriteRule ^(admin)$ admin/index.php` and tell me what you see in the address bar.

Comment: It just adds a slash to the end, and does to a 404, because I haven't specified "admin" as a page (Because it was supposed to be a folder)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond lines can be strung together as you have them, but they only impact the first rule they come to.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

This will send all requests for non-existent directories and files to index.php. Files and directories that exist won't be impacted. The other rules are unnecessary.

Comment: Would work, if it wasn't for the fact, that I've rewrote the next param too D: (Updated my question)

Comment: 1 - rename the admin directory to cms. 2 - Please read the documentation for mod_rewrite, specifically RewriteCond: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: sorry, was supposed to be named admin, just a typo

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

You are rewriting to a directory named `admin` which obvously exists in your file system as such Apache says:

`if this path does not exist as a directory path or as a file path continue with the rewrites`

That is why it is not quite rewriting the way you would expect.